# SFML problems - sfml-graphics-s.lib(Image.cpp.obj) LNK2001

Tags: c++, sfml

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and downloaded SFML Visual C++ 15 (2017) - 32-bit package.
I don't know anything, I just do whatever the setup tutorial said in this link: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php
And I've got into this:

```html
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
 sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
 sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
 shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

 while (window.isOpen())
 {
  sf::Event event;
  while (window.pollEvent(event))
  {
   if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
    window.close();
  }

  window.clear();
  window.draw(shape);
  window.display();
 }

 return 0;
}
```

```html
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___std_swap_ranges_trivially_swappable_noalias Chess D:\Learning Stuff\3rd Year\NM CNPM\Chess\Chess\sfml-graphics-s.lib(Image.cpp.obj) 1 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals Chess D:\Learning Stuff\3rd Year\NM CNPM\Chess\Release\Chess.exe 1
```

. My problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLWRt.jpg

. My .lib Input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jigPm.jpg

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Please share your code as raw instead of the image. So that it can help others

Comment: Sorry, I forgot!

Comment: They say you need VS 15.7.0: https://twitter.com/sfmldev/status/997527379374419968

Comment: Thank you so much! I just updated my VS and it works!